# Conditional Logic for getting a list of sub categories in ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am creating a business listings and Advanced Custom Field (ACF) helps me to create the backend form.

The question is, how do I get the sub category of a main category only if I set the condition.

**For example,**

- I have 100s of City names as *City Taxonomy*
- I have 100s of Area names as sub category of the *City Taxonomy*

I have created a form that includes these 2 fields.

- City:_________ (Drop down selection of *City Taxonomy*)
- Area Name:_______ (**I want this sub category drop down to show up based on City selection above**)

**Is this possible?** Or does it require coding to make it work?
I have searched enough and I could not find even a premium plugins to support this.

---

I can simply set these 2 fields to pull data from *City Taxonomy* but the data entry becomes very tough with hyphen appearing before *sub-city Taxonomies* and possible duplicate value under different city.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to code this.

Comment: You'll need to make a new field type (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-new-field-type/) to construct a chained select.